# How to submit values from a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

Hi all I have a view with these controls on it

```
<input type="text" class="radius2" />
<input type="button" value="Place bid" class="bid-btn" />
```

I want to pass the value in the text box to another view (via an action method) when the button is clicked.  The action method should render the view.

How can this be acheived?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SubmitAction", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <input id="radius2" name="radius2" type="text" class="radius2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Place bid" class="bid-btn" />

}
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitAction(string radius2)
    {
       return AnotherView(radius2);
    }

    public ActionResult AnotherView(string value)
    {
       return View(); 
    }
```

Written in notepad so might require small syntax changes

Answer (score 1):

add name property to the tags so the server can access them

```
<input name="Name1" type="text" class="radius2" />
<input type="button" value="Place bid" class="bid-btn" />
```

then when submit your action should be something like this

```
public ActionResult SubmitAction(string name1)
{
  return View("ViewName" , /* the model here */ )
}
```

Comment: I believe the type should be "submit"